# Sub Process with Browser Choice

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, subprocess

I write a TC that allows me to run in any Browser when I input, but I wonder how I can run multiple test case in test suite by sub process (in case I have many test cases in test suite like that). I imagine that I cannot enter browser name in each TC. Could you advice me?

-- MyTC.py:

```
class TC_01_Check_Get_OPOS_Version(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        vr_Input_Browser    = 'Please choose Browser that you want to run'
        vr_Selected_Browser = input(vr_Input_Browser)
        #-- Run with Selected Browser:
        if vr_Selected_Browser == "Chrome":
           self.Driver = webdriver.Chrome()        
        elif vr_Selected_Browser == "Firefox":
           self.Driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install()))
        #-- Open WebPage/ URL:
            self.Driver.get(vr_TC_01_WebPage)
            time.sleep(3)
            self.Driver.maximize_window()

    def test_1(self):
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        time.sleep(10)
        self.Driver.quit()
```

-- MyTestSuite.py:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run  ("MyTC1.py",    shell=True)
subprocess.run  ("MyTC2.py",    shell=True)
subprocess.run  ("MyTC3.py",    shell=True)
subprocess.run  ("MyTC4.py",    shell=True)
```

With my above code, I cannot run my test suite because each TC require me to input browser name

Comment: What does "TC" mean in this context? Test case?

Comment: The proper solution is obviously to not require interactive input. Hard-code the browser choice, provide a fallback option, or a way to specify the choice programmatically.

Comment: The duplicate feels slightly unfair; if you can [edit] to provide a more specific question, we might be able to reopen this.